# Angular/Pug - Can't bind to 'ngforOf' since

Tags: html, angular, intellij-idea, pug

1. This code is throwing exception

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngforOf' since
>   it isn't a known property of 'mat-card'.
>   1. If 'mat-card' is an Angular component and it has 'ngforOf' input, then verify that it is part of this module.

```
div
  button(mat-raised-button, color='primary', (click)='createMocked()') Create Mocked
  div
    mat-card.Class(*ngfor="let room of rooms; let classroomIndex = index; trackBy: trackClass")
```

[image]

2. if I will add quotes then I'm missing support from Intellij
   [image]

Does anyone have idea how to fix 1 and 2 or have woking in intellij reference that I can check?
I used this article: https://medium.com/@MarkPieszak/using-pug-or-jade-templates-with-the-angular-cli-9e37334db5bc

Comment: You are right thanks, please post your answer to the whole thread, so I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

> Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngforOf' since it isn't a known
>   property

means that Angular template parser tries to find a directive based on your `ngforof` attribute but it can't since **Angular template syntax is case-sensitive**.

You have to write `*ngFor=` so it will converted to `ngForOf` and Angular will be able to find dedicated ngForOf directive.

If you're curious how Angular transforms structural directives into ng-template syntax then check this out:

- https://alexzuza.github.io/ng-structural-directive-expander/